# renderPM.drawToFile printing a lot fo stuff

Tags: python

So iam trying to save SVG to PNG, and finally found a way,
but for some reason:

this code:

```
f = open('file.svg', 'w')
f.write(drawing)
f.close()

drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "file.png", fmt="png")
```

Yields this output:
[image]

how to silence this?